# Why escape sequence "\a" doesn't produce sound in Windows Form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, beep

I'm using visual studio and I've created a windows form application for C#. I tried the codes:

```
//1st
textBox1.Text = "\a";
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

and

```
//2nd
Messagebox.Show("\a");
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

and

```
//3rd
Console.WriteLine("\a");
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

but none of these codes produced any sounds from the \a escape sequence.
However, when I tried the 3rd set of codes on a Console application instead,
it worked. What codes should I use to allow the \a escape sequence to work and produce a sound on windows form application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `\a` is only interpreted as beep by the console window. To play a beep sound in a windows forms application you can use:

```
SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

See this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-play-a-beep-from-a-windows-form).

Comment: Not the same beep sound.